# Show that if $n$ is even and larger than 2, then $n^3−4n$ is always divisible by 48.

Tags: solution-verification, induction, divisibility

I have done the following but could not have made the final conclusion!

Base case: $n=4$ then $(4^3-4 \times 4)|48=1$ that holds true.

Hypothesis: assume $n=k$ then $(k^3-4k)|48$ always holds true so $(k^3-4k)=48m$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Proof: take $n=k+1$ then show that $((k+1)^3-4(k+1))|48$ also holds true:

$$(k^3+3k^2+3k+1-4k-1)|48$$

$$((k^3-4k)+3k^2+3k)|48$$
$$(48m+3k^2+3k)|48$$
$$3(16m+k^2+k)|48$$

This is where I am stuck! I know $16m+k^2+k$ is already an integer but I cannot conclude the divisibility holds true in the last line. Any advice or clue?

Comment: Since $n$ is even, the induction step is $k+2$, not $k+1$.

Comment: I wonder why was this question downvoted. OP showed his work, it is a good question.

Comment: Just a quick remark concerning your notation: As far as I know the expression $m \mid n$ usually means that $m$ divides $n$, you seem to use it the other way around or to denote a fraction like in $(4^3 - 4 \cdot 4)/48 = 1$.

Comment: The clue is that you forgot that this only holds for even numbers. (For example, for $n=4$ your computation to $n+1=5$ will not work).

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=2k+2,$ where $k$ is a natural number.

Thus, $$n^3-4n=n(n-2)(n+2)=8k(k+1)(k+2).$$
Now, we see that $k(k+1)(k+2)$ is divisible by $6$ because one of the numbers $k$, $k+1$ and $k+2$ is divisible by $3$ and one of the numbers $k$ and $k+1$ is divisible by $2$,  which gives that you wish.

Comment: @bof In the given $n>2$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg But he’s right, your substitution assumes $n=2k$, else you’d get $8k(k+1)(k+2)$.

Comment: @Lazy  Thank you! I fixed

Comment: @bof The statement is generally true for any even integer.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg how can we see $k(k+1)(k+2)$ is divisible by 6? Also, how come do you take $n=2k+2$ since we already know $k$ ought to be even.

Comment: @Ham64 Note that at least one of $k,(k+1),(k+2)$ is divsible by $2$ and at least one is divisible by $3$. Thus the product is divisible by $6$.  Note that Michael uses $k$ differently than you. He uses $k$ so that $n=2k+2$ with $k$ some Integer. In your notation this would be $n=k+2$ with $k$ some even integer.

Comment: @Ham64 I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

As lhf has stated in the comments you need to make the step to $k+2$. Then
$$ (k+2)^3-4(k+2) - (k^3-4k) = 6k^2+12 k$$
If $k=2l$ then this is $6\cdot 4 l^2+12\cdot 2 l = 48 l$.

But rather you can prove this directly: If $n=2k$, then
$$ n^3-4n = 8k^3-8k = 8k(k^2-1) $$
Now we know that either $2|k$ or $2|k^2-1$ (if $k\equiv 1\mod2$ then $k^2\equiv1\mod 2$) and we know that either $3|k$ or $k^2\equiv 1\mod 3$, so $3|k^2-1$. Thus $6|k(k^2-1)$ and thus $8\cdot6=48|n$.

By the way: We do not need $n>2$. It holds true also for $n=2$ and $n=0$ and generally for every even integer.

Comment: in the second line, it should be $6k^2+12k+4$, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, as $(k+2)^3-4(k+2) = k^3+6k^2+12k+8-4k-8$, so the constant term cancels out, and $k^3-4k$ is known to be a multiple of $48$ by induction hypothesis.